Application context get bean in spring native image
I am creating a bean using the method :
public <T, E> MyClient<T, E> createMyClient(Class<T> AType, Class<E> BType) {
       return applicationContext.getBean(MyClient.class, aType, bType);
    }

Create native image using native profile in spring boot 3. What is the recommended way to create the image so that getBean method returns the proper object ?
